# Why is the dative "einem Menschen" used here?

Tags: dative

Why is the dative *einem Menschen* used in the sentence below?

> Von *einem Menschen* mit einem echten spirituellen Meister erwartet man, daß er alles weiß.

Comment: Because "von" requires Dativ (question word: von wem oder was?, just like "from/by whom" in English)

Comment: @Connum, you make this more immediately helpful to a native English speaker if you replace "whom" by "him". And that will still not give any hint on whether it should be accusative or dative.

Comment: @Connum then is there an exception in below sentence.     Alle vedischen Schriften geben uns den Rat, einen spirituellen Meister aufzusuchen, um von den Verwirrungen des Lebens frei zu werden, die auftreten, ohne daß wir es uns wünschen

Comment: "die Verwirrungen" is feminine, and female plural Dativ is "von den ...". So, there's no exception.